# Protractor wait for isElementPresent and click on waited element fails

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a issue with my end2end tests.  Sometimes they pass without any problem but two thirds of the time they fail. I use protractor with following code:

```
 describe('Admin dashboard delete Exports', function () {
        it('create export', function () {
            browser.get(e2GUrl + '/admin/studies');
            ptor.wait(function() {
                return ptor.isElementPresent(by.id('export'));
            }, 5000, 'wait for study list page to be loaded.');
            element(by.id('export')).click();
         });
```

HTML (note that this element is visible and not hidden by ng-if or ng-show):

```
 <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="study in studies">
       <div data-ng-controller="ExportController" class="btn-group">
          <a id="export" class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
             <i class="fw-icon fw-icon-cloud-download"></i>Export
                <span class="caret"></span>
           </a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu export-list">
                <li class="excel"><a data-ng-click="excel(study.Code)">Export to Excel</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Error I receive:

> E2E: Admin dashboard delete Exports create export Message:
>   NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("export")

Comment: if i comment out the click action it runs fine everytime

Comment: What if you add `browser.waitForAngular();` after the `get()` call?

Comment: doens't seems to work still fails sometimes

Comment: Does your element flicker? Try doing something like this 'for (i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {element(by.id('export')).isPresent().then(function(present) {console.log(present)}); browser.sleep(100)}'

Comment: found the issue and shared the solution thanks for the replies and aid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found out there the issue is in the difference between: 
`element` `isPresent()` and `isDisplayed()`

so if you wait for only `isPresent()` it could be found in html but not yet displayed.

tricky if you just want to use `elm.isDisplayed()` only, it will crash if the element doesn’t exist yet. So you have to check first is `isPresent()` before `isDisplayed()`

I made a function that waits blocking for the 2 properties:

```
this.waitUntilReady = function (elm) {
        browser.wait(function () {
            return elm.isPresent();
        },10000);
        browser.wait(function () {
            return elm.isDisplayed();
        },10000);
    };

describe('Admin dashboard delete Exports', function () {
        it('create export', function () {
            browser.get(e2GUrl + '/admin/studies');
            waitUntilReady(element(by.id('export')));
            element(by.id('export')).click();
         });
```